# AJAX MVC call not being properly formed. parameters scrambled

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I am calling a AJAX refresh of a MVC4, and I debug in google chrome.

The text is below. the ogid is a number (as text).

The script below works - up to a point. It generates the following url

`http://localhost:54534/AddInschrijvingen/ListKandidaten?id%5B%5D=9`

```
            <script>
            $("#OpdrachtgeversID").change(function () {
                var ogid = $("#OpdrachtgeversID").val();                    
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'AddInschrijvingen/ListKandidaten',
                    type: 'GET',                                             
                    data: { id: ogid },                        
                    succes: function(data) {
                        $('#StatesDivID').html(data)
                    }

                })
            })
        </script>
```

if I replace the data: { id: ogid} by { id: 7} it generates the following:

```
http://localhost:54534/AddInschrijvingen/ListKandidaten?id=7
```

The last is what I need, but I still need it formed with a variable. What am I missing?

Comment: So what value is `ogid` when it gets to the ajax call?  Because I'd guess it's not `7`.

Comment: using alert(ogid), it showed as a integer - with no funny business

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try by `parseInt`

```
 var ogid = parseInt($("#OpdrachtgeversID").val(), 10);
```

`%5B%5D` means `[]`, may be your `ogid` may not have correct number as you expected.

Comment: These two characters appeared before the = sign - so I assumed the id part wasn't converted correctly. However... it works. and now generates a clear id=7, instead of id%5B%5D=7. Thank you